# location of base class object inside derived class object

Tags: c++, pointers, object, inheritance

If I have a derived class object, will base class object always be located at the start of this object ?

For example in the code below, will A's object guaranteed to be placed at the start of object of B in all implementations.

I have seen this placement of base members always but don't know if its a defined standard. Also if this is the case, how does it work with multiple inheritance ?

```
class A
{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
        int c;
        int d;
};

int main ()
{
    B obj;

    // Is B.a always guaranteed to be at the top i.e. 
    // Object arranged as
    /*
    {
       a;
       b;
       c;
       d;
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: If this is in the standard, I'm interested to see how it works with multiple inheritance.

Comment: Why do you wonder? What is the *actual* problem you have?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I will be passing this object for conversion to a C struct that will pass it on further. If I know how its packed, I can do the conversion using pointers. generic conversion functions is not what I am looking for, just info on c++ packing standard for object. :)

Comment: @Siddharth That sounds like asking for trouble for me. Maybe you should read up on serialization.

Comment: The order in which base class objects are allocated is unspecified (chapter 10, paragraph 5), so a compiler is free to allocate B's members before A's.  I don't know of any that do, though.  If you need to pass classes to C directly, this will only work with POD types (no virtual functions, no private or protected members).  Better would be to copy the C++ data to a C `struct`.

Comment: If you want to convert a pointer to B to a pointer to A, just cast it. The compiler will take care of adjusting the offset if necessary.